# Web.Config might be “unreadable”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5

I am having a rather strange issue. When I debug from within VS2015, I am able to use and interact with the site without any issues, however it takes such a long time to compile every time I want to check something out by debugging. Plus, once I start debugging, files are locked and cannot be edited; and when I stop debugging the internal IIS to VS crashes (this is for any site I work with, not just this one). So using the IIS internal to VS2015 is not possible without being in debugging mode.

When I attach the local installation of IIS Express to either the directory that the project files are in, or to the directory that the compiled project is spat out into, the site works only with normal pages. Any Actions that involve database requests fail with a 500 server error. Other sites that have the same setup (installed IIS pointing toward project directory) work just fine, however this one fails on any Action that requires a DB connection:

> Most likely causes:
>
> - IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
> - IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
> - IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
> - The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
> - The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> - Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
> - Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
> - Verify the permissions for the DLL.
> - Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
> - Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module         ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification   ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler        System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL  http://project.localhost:80/Home/Test
Physical Path  D:\Source\Repos\Project\Project\Home\Test
Logon Method   Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

I have looked into the permissions for Web.Config, but they are all good, with both IUSR and IIS_IUSRS being given read/execute permissions. The application pool is set to Integrated, and this doesn’t seem to be an IIS issue *specifically* because a number of other database-driven sites on the machine work just fine (I just leave them up because I do frequent maintenance). So here I am thinking that this might be a Web.Config issue, at least in terms of how it is set up (again, permissions are identical to the other sites on the machine). And yet, the version of IIS built into Visual Studio works just fine with the site… it just dies (crashes) whenever debugging is stopped (this is with any site).

So I am looking for suggestions -- what could be making the version of IIS built into VS2015 work correctly, but the IIS in Windows fail with any DB connection in my current site? Keep in mind that the Windows IIS works with other sites and the static pages in this one, just not Actions that have DB access of any kind.

I am hoping that someone might be able to tell me if something is wrong with my Web.Config or not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="nwebsec">
      <section name="httpHeaderSecurityModule" type="NWebsec.Modules.Configuration.HttpHeaderSecurityConfigurationSection, NWebsec, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3613da5f958908a1" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="censored" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Elmah" connectionString="censored" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
    <add key="recaptchaPublicKey" value="censored" />
    <add key="recaptchaPrivateKey" value="censored" />
    <add key="recaptchaApiVersion" value="2" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/Error/Index">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="/Error/Unauthorized" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/Forbidden" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <add name="NWebsecHttpHeaderSecurityModule" type="NWebsec.Modules.HttpHeaderSecurityModule, NWebsec, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3613da5f958908a1" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Forbidden" />
    </httpErrors>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="NWebsecConfig" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AngleSharp" publicKeyToken="e83494dcdc6d31ea" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.9.6.41832" newVersion="0.9.6.41832" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <!--<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />-->
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="info@lawyercase.ca">
        <network host="" port="587" userName="" password="" enableSsl="false" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <nwebsec>
    <httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NWebsecConfig/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd">
      <redirectValidation enabled="true" />
      <securityHttpHeaders>
        <x-Frame-Options policy="Deny" />
        <x-Content-Type-Options enabled="true" />
      </securityHttpHeaders>
    </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
  </nwebsec>
  <elmah xmlns="http://Elmah.Configuration">
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->  
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Without knowing a specific exception that's occurring, it is really hard to say what's wrong. The first things I would look at is database permissions. Specifically, does the identity running the application pool have access to the database (assuming you are using integrated security). If that doesn't work, I'd change Elmah to write to a file so that you can see what's going on.

Comment: The strange thing is, Elmah is working just fine… from inside the VS2015 IIS. I have 40+ entries detailing the issues I ran into during development. But for some reason this site doesn’t work from the Windows IIS.

Comment: Have you checked database permissions? Because that does seem like the most likely problem.

Comment: I am… unsure how that affects things. I have just one MSSQL database, but two copies of IIS on my system: one for Windows, the other a part of VS2015. Both copies of IIS make use of the same Web.Config, and both access the same DB. And this is across multiple sites set up on this machine. The only difference is that the Windows IIS has issues making a connection from that site specifically -- all other sites work just fine.

Comment: @JeffSilver the problem was *kind of* related to DB permissions -- just from an angle that I would not have usually considered. Please see my answer for the resulting facepalm. Thank you for your help.

Comment: check the connection string in application and remote server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of a *Mea Culpa* here, as the information that would point out the problem most obviously to potential Good Samaritans was censored by me. Why? Because I didn’t want to share the DB `connectionString` with world+dog.

Turns out that a default Web.Config will also include, in the `DefaultConnection` `connectionString`, the term `Integrated Security=True`. Why is this a problem? Because this is telling IIS to use Integrated Security when accessing the DB -- as in, ignore the Username and Password, and just use its own credentials.

Which, of course, is an Epic Fail.

Now, I am not sure how the IIS built into Visual Studio 2015 is ignoring and/or bypassing this term. Either it ignores it altogether and just uses the Username and Password in the string, or the installation of Visual Studio somehow sets up an automatic handshake between VS and MSSQL. I just don’t know.

Let’s chalk this entire clusterfuck to this being my first truly independent (no prior version) project I have worked on to date. In all other cases I had a prior version of the site (and as such, the DB) to work from, and I must have just copied over the `connectionString` as a whole unit from the old project instead of just editing the one in the new project.

TL;DR: Altering the `connectionString` to `Integrated Security=False` or removing it altogether solves the problem with standalone IIS (IIS not integrated into Visual Studio) not being able to access the DB despite the IIS built into Visual Studio doing just fine.

Comment: You don't need to change it in root web.config. Simply override it in your own web.config. Study the hierarchical design and how to properly override.

Comment: I am talking about the Web.Config in the root of the project folder. You know, the one that will sit at the root of the website’s httpdocs once the site is uploaded. No need to override anything, this is where everything goes anyhow. I am not talking about Web.Config files in subfolders.

Answer (score -2):

it was solve for me by restart Visual studio.